# Is it possible to use the Maven POM file for the configuration of GIT Tag for the maven release plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I want to use the Maven Release plugin for preparing a release by adding a GIT TAG to the commit with ONLY the version number for example  1.0.0  .  And I want to be able to set the prefix for the commit message.
Right now the default tag is like this:  project-name-1.0.0 .
The commit message is also added by the maven Release plugin in the prepare phase and it has a prefix of this: [maven-release-plugin]

These default values are generated in the release:prepare phase and they are put in the release.properties file.

I would like to set the variables default somewhere in the maven POM file so that every  Release has the same default parameters for the GIT tag and the prefix for the commit message.

Anybody know how to do this ?

This is a part of my POM file, there are no other parameters at this moment for the maven-release.

```
<scm>
        <connection>scm:git:https://example@example/mq-copy.git</connection>
        <url>https://example@example/mq-copy.git</url>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:https://example@example/mq-copy.git</developerConnection>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
  </scm>
```

And this is the generated release.properties file:

```
#release configuration
#Tue Jun 23 22:30:00 CEST 2020
scm.tagNameFormat=@{project.artifactId}-@{project.version}
scm.tag=mq-copy-2.0.4
pushChanges=true
scm.url=scm\:git\:https\://example@example/mq-copy.git
preparationGoals=clean verify
project.dev.nl.bpittens.mq\:mq-copy=2.0.5-SNAPSHOT
remoteTagging=true
projectVersionPolicyId=default
scm.commentPrefix=[maven-release-plugin] 
project.scm.nl.bpittens.mq\:mq-copy.connection=scm\:git\:https\://example@example/mq-copy.git
project.scm.nl.bpittens.mq\:mq-copy.developerConnection=scm\:git\:https\://example@example/mq-copy.git
project.rel.nl.bpittens.mq\:mq-copy=2.0.4
project.scm.nl.bpittens.mq\:mq-copy.tag=HEAD
exec.snapshotReleasePluginAllowed=false
exec.additionalArguments=-P sagro
completedPhase=end-release
project.scm.nl.bpittens.mq\:mq-copy.url=https\://example@example/mq-copy.git
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer for a part of the problem. But it answers this particular question. I have just to add the  plugin with configuration parameters like this in the pom.xml file in the plugins section:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <configuration>
         <tag>${project.version}</tag>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```